# heroku app domain works but custom domain gives 400 error

Tags: django, heroku, dns

I've recently deployed a (django) app to heroku and although the app works fine on the default heroku app domain `appname.herokuapp.com` it doesn't work at the custom url `www.appname.com` it instead gives a 400 bad request error.

The domain dns has been configured at namecheap.com but domain added to heroku via:

```
$ heroku domains:add appname.com,
$ heroku domains:add www.appname.com
```

what's the best way to diagnose the error as currently the app on heroku doesn't seem to be generating any errors (ie none showing in opbeat which captured earlier errors fine - apart from the custom domain routing, everything is working fine).

Comment: Did you add `appname.com` and `www.appname.com` to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: thanks that was it. I had added `appname.herokuapp.com` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but didn't realise that django could see any of the custom domains.

Comment: If you add your comment to the answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that you may not have those domains added to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

To correct the error, try doing the following in your settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'appname.com',
    'www.appname.com',
    'appname.herokuapp.com',
    ...
]
```